# Find an element in a collection, that can become relevant after another item is found

Tags: java, algorithm

I've been having some trouble coming up with an efficient algorithm for the following problem, and I was wondering if anyone here might be able to help me out. And no, it's not homework. Any help is appreciated!

Say I have a collection with the following elements: {A, B, C, D, .... Z}.

Each element has certain lock requirements that can be met, and meeting these requirements can unlock other elements in the collection.

Initially, while looping through the collection, element A is locked, but subsequent iterations on the collection bring me to element D, and after processing element D, I gain the required components to be able to use element A. Similarly, element L is initially locked, but after processing element O, element L can be processed.

Apart from looping twice or in reverse over the collection, and sorting the collection, is there another way to process all elements in a single loop?

Comment: What do you mean by "locked"?

Comment: If the item is locked, move it to the end of the collection, so once all unlocked items are porcessed you can check them again.
You will have to have a check when to break the loop though otherwise it will run forever if there are elements that will not be unlocked.

Comment: That it needs a "key" to be able to unlock and process it. These "keys" are given out after processing an element

Comment: Is there any logic to which letters are unlocked by other letters? What happens if you try to process a locked element? An exception is thrown?

Comment: Please provide more info about how the key system works: Does every chest need exactly one key to unlock it? Can you reuse the same key? How many keys may the chests contain? With how many keys you start with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well - If you know which elements might get unlocked from accessing an element, you can visit them next - since they are more likely to be unlocked - you should always keep a pointer to the place your initial linear search has reached - and perhaps a counter to see if you've been through all elements -so that you can resume from here if your visit to another element isn't fruitful. This wont lower Big O though - but might improve average time. This assumes that you can do a search in O(1) time though.
Else I like the idea of moving locked elements to the end - or even better removing unlocked elements (since this will max add n time moving elements)- that'll save some time traversing the array/list/SearchTree